# Magento2 Stop abandonment cart email to be fired when quote value is restored

Tags: magento2

Magento2, I am using Hosted Pro Paypal. I am having issue where abandonment cart email gets fired when the cart is restored. I want to stop this mail.

For restoring the data I have used below code

[image]

Comment: don't have a clue what you are on about? can you explain why you add this code so that instread of a bug we understand your intention?

Comment: The reason for my restoring the quote data is, I am using Hosted Paypal pro, so after clicking on continue button Paypal frame is loaded on checkout page, ideally magento places order when we click on continue & cart gets cleared when Paypal frame is loaded. I want to provide user the option to change even after Paypal frame is loaded. So I restored data. But due to some reason on restoring data abandoned cart mail also gets fired