# Magento2 When does magento considers a cart to be abandoned

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I would like to know when does Magento consider a cart to be Abandoned.

In short, is there any specific changes made in cart or cart table when notifies that the  cart is abandoned cart.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a cart in Magento, a `quote` record is created and specifically the field `is_active` is set to 1. It will remain to 1 until the order is placed and successful.

However, no `customer_id` or `customer_email` is assigned to the quote record until the customer has signed in.

the exact query the show the abandoned cart is:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, (main_table.base_subtotal_with_discount*main_table.base_to_global_rate) AS `subtotal` FROM `quote` AS `main_table` WHERE (`items_count` != '0') AND (`main_table`.`is_active` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`customer_id` != '') ORDER BY updated_at DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

In short, only cart for a registered customer will have an abandoned cart afterwards. The Abandoned Cart report screen in Magento Backend does show the record even though the cart may be active and genuinely about to create an order. (that may be confusing to you)

Comment: Thanks for sharing details. I have a question, in my case as soon as cart is restored after order is placed, it is considering cart to be abandoned.

Comment: Best is to update your question and I can try to improve my answer. If the question is very different, you might to create a new question. As your comment stands, I am unsure what you mean by ‘Cart is restored’

Comment: Here I have added ques https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314895/magento2-stop-abandonment-cart-email-to-be-fired-when-quote-value-is-restored. I am in a big trouble due to this?